# Cant change the color of programmatically created UINavigationController on dark mode

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios-darkmode

Im creating navigation view programmatically and I want white navigation bar on dark mode. I thought I did everything right but on dark mode im still getting dark navbar

```
 let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: weatherMain)
 navVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
 navVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
 navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
 present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Although some answers suggest .backgroundColor or .tintColor, they don't  help me at all. I cant figure out how to solve

Answer (score 0):

You can this in your `AppDelegate` file which will help you to change the colors:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7415059209, green: 0.5448099971, blue: 0.5051562786, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(red: 0.7415059209, green: 0.5448099971, blue: 0.5051562786, alpha: 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `preferredStatusBarStyle`

maybe you can try overriding these functions for the UINavigationController:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.darkContent
    } else {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(false)
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```